# Assign data frame name to list elements using name vector

Tags: r, assign, data-management

I have a data frame, 'mydata':

```
head(mydata)

ID      MDC
000001  21A
000002  5
000003  8
...
```

I've split my data frame by one of it's column values, namely 'MDC'. This created a list, subdivided into further lists by the column value 'MDC':

```
mylist <- split(mydata, mydata$MDC, drop=TRUE)
summary(mylist)

    Length Class      Mode
0   75     data.frame list
1   75     data.frame list
10  75     data.frame list
11  75     data.frame list
12  75     data.frame list
21A 75     data.frame list
...
```

I now want to create a data frame for each MDC with the corresponding name, e.g. 'MDC1'.
How can I assign the MDC values to the list elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this should work

```
MDC <- paste0("MDC", sort(unique(mydata$MDC)))
names(mylist) <- MDC
list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
ls() # Checking environment
## [1] "MDC"    "MDC21A" "MDC5"   "MDC8"   "mydata" "mylist"
```

**Edit:**
Per @flodel's comment- In case you want to make further operations on these data frames, you shouldn't copy them into the global environment. You should leave them in `mylist` and do all your operation on that list using functions such as `lapply` and `rapply`

Comment: I am torn between upvoting or downvoting. If you understand why this is a bad pratice and what would be a better one, please elaborate and you'll definitely get my upvote.

Comment: @flodel, if you think it is a bad practice, I will definitely delete this. From your comment in the question I didn't see how is it different from what the OP already did

Comment: @flodel, correct me if I am mistaken but your code is exactly what I posted in my question. What I wanted is 27 data frames, named 'MDC1', 'MDC2' etc.

Comment: It is bad practice because 1) your solution via `.GlobalEnv` is not very portable and 2) a list of data.frames (via `split(mydata, mydata$MDC)`) is in 99% cases a better choice. Next thing you know, the OP is going to post a question asking how to do something with  each of his `MDC*` objects. And someone will suggest he uses `get`, `mget` or `eval(parse(text=...))`...

Comment: @user3243793. Yes, David answered exactly the question as you asked it, i.e. how to create `n` data.frames. What I am saying is that you would be better off keeping your single object: a list of `n` data.frames. And work with that.

Comment: @flodel, he already did that. But I see what you mean, so I made an edit. Hope this is what you meant

Comment: @flodel is absolutely right. The R way is to work with lists, or in "big data" cases maybe with environments, but **not** putting objects into the global environment.

Comment: @MartinMächler, Are you saying that you never should work with data frames, only with lists?

Comment: @David Arenburg: No, not at all. I'm saying that it is wrong to put a list of objects into the globalenv, and typically in 99% cases rather do work with list()s, in your case with a list of data frames.

Comment: @MartinMächler So the correct answer for this question is: "Don't do this. Period."?