# How to load all variables in a R data frame to working space?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R but want all of the variables in the data frame to be single variables in my working space instead. So, I am looking for a command where I just use `command(df)` in the code below and I have `Var_A`, `Var_B`, `Var_C` in my working space.

```
data <- 1:12
df <- data.frame(matrix(data, ncol = 3))
names(df) <- c("Var_A", "Var_B", "Var_C")
df

> df
  Var_A Var_B Var_C
1     1     5     9
2     2     6    10
3     3     7    11
4     4     8    12
```

EDIT: My question is not an exact duplicate of the suggested question. The suggested question asks why it is not good to do what I want. There is a difference in asking how to do something and why doing something might be bad. Moreover, I don't understand the downvotes. I stated a clear question with a reproucible code sample. Instead of voting me down because one thinks it is a bad thing what I want to do, one could simply answer and propose an alternative.

Comment: Why do you need to create all the objects in the global environment?  It is not so good

Comment: attach()ing a data.frame is probably never a good idea. It is a huge cause of bugs, and there are many better alternatives, for example with() or the data argument in functions that take a formula

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I stated a clear question with a reproucible code sample. Instead of voting me down because one thinks it is a bad thing what I want to do, one could simply answer and propose an alternative.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi if you want to do that you can do :

```
list2env(x = df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
Var_A
# [1] 1 2 3 4
ls()
# [1] "data"  "df"    "Var_A" "Var_B" "Var_C"
```

**EDIT** you should probably keep your variables in your `data.frame`, or at least in a `list`, there's probably an other way to do what you want to do with `data.frame`.

Comment: Brilliant!! I came up with an solution that split to single dataframes.. little non sense.. anyway for sake of discussion... `for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  assign(paste(names(df)[i]), df[i])
}`

Comment: See this comment from the author of `list2env` himself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761656/assign-data-frame-name-to-list-elements-using-name-vector/25761850#comment40331663_25761850

Comment: I agree, I can't find a case where this is the right thing to do, but i do not know what the OP wants to do with that

Comment: I agree with both of you. Not a good practice, but sometimes happens you need this approach.. in 1% of the cases according to the author of `list2env` :). I have been in that 1% too

Comment: I never used this before and afterwards. I needed it for one thing.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but here it goes:

```
decomposeFrame <- function(df){
  vars <- colnames(df)

  sapply(vars, function(x){
    eval(parse(text = paste0(x, "<<- ", "df$", x)))
    })
}
```